# Dependent dropdownlist in ASP.NET MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, dropdown

At present I have two tables (Teams and Employees)
I am populating the dropdownList for Teams perfectly, next I am trying to populate the second dropdownlist depending on the selectedId of Teams for Employees.

Controller:

```
 // GET: CalView
        public ActionResult Index(string ses, string DH)
        {     //Team Lead Members
                var eID = Convert.ToInt32(Session["currentEmployeeID"]);
                var EmpID = Session["currentEmpID"];
                Employee obj = (from o in db.Employees
                                where o.EnrollNumber == EmpID
                                select o).FirstOrDefault();

                Department dept = (from dep in db.Departments
                                   where dep.LeadBy == obj.EmployeeId
                                   select dep).FirstOrDefault();
                //this works fine
                ViewBag.showTeams = new SelectList(db.Teams.Where(tm => (tm.DeptID == dept.DepartmentId) && (dept.LeadBy == eID)), "TeamID","Name");
               //this obviously does not
                ViewBag.showMembers = new SelectList(db.Employees.Where(empt => (empT.TeamID == selectedIdFromPreviousDropDownList), "EmployeeID", "Employee"));

                return View();
        }
```

View:

```
if ((Session["UT"] == "DD") && (@ViewBag.DeptLead != null))
  {
//this works
  @Html.DropDownList("showTeams", null, "-Select Team-", htmlAttributes: new { @class = "form-control" })
//this does not work
  @Html.DropDownList("showMembers", null, "-Select Team-", htmlAttributes: new { @class = "form-control" })
   }
```

Do I need some AJAX call? or perhaps a POST method? Totally new to MVC.

Comment: Yes, I think the best way to do it, is making an **Ajax** call, are you using JQuery?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Cascading Dropdown lists MVC 3 C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10016560/cascading-dropdown-lists-mvc-3-c-sharp)

Comment: Suggest you study the code in [this DotNetFiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/1bPZym) to understand how to implement cascading dropdownlists

Answer (score 9, accepted):

*Do I need some AJAX call? or perhaps a POST method?* Okay then, lets do it this way:

Give your DropdownLists some id's probably:

```
 @Html.DropDownList("showTeams", null, "-Select Team-", htmlAttributes: new { id = "ddshowTeams", @class = "form-control" })
 @Html.DropDownList("showMembers", null, "-Select Team-", htmlAttributes: new {id = "ddshowMembers", @class = "form-control" })
```

Create a jsonResult function, `GetMembers` and some Magic right there:

```
<script type="text/javascript">

        $(document).ready(function () {
            //Dropdownlist Selectedchange event
            $("#ddshowTeams").change(function () {
                console.log("pehla andar");
                $("#ddshowMembers").empty();
                $.ajax({
                    type: 'POST',
                    url: '@Url.Action("GetMembers")',
                    dataType: 'json',
                    data: { id: $("#ddshowTeams").val() },
                    success: function (mems) {
                        console.log("wich ayaeee");
                        // states contains the JSON formatted list
                        // of states passed from the controller
                        $.each(mems, function (i, member) {
                            $("#ddshowMembers").append('<option value="'
    + member.Value + '">'
    + member.Text + '</option>');
                        });
                    },
                    error: function (ex) {
                        alert('Failed to retrieve states.' + ex);
                    }
                });
                return false;
            })
        });
</script>
```

and in your controller:

```
 public JsonResult GetMembers(int id)
        {
            return Json(new SelectList(db.Employees.Where(empt => (empt.TeamId == id)), "EmployeeID", "FirstName"));
        }
```